# Good starting point for Natural Language Processing thesis

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I want to do a masters thesis on Natural Language Processing, where I want to evaluate if given definitions meet certain criterias. Problem is, I'm new to NLP and I don't know where to start. I need a paper with a NLP method appropriate for my problem so that I can build on that paper.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't understand your question. Are you trying to familiarize yourself with NLP before starting a Master?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without knowing what your problem is. Some of Sebastian Ruder's work comes to mind that might help you narrow your focus - [A Review of the Neural History of Natural Language Processing](https://ruder.io/a-review-of-the-recent-history-of-nlp/) and [Tracking Progress in Natural Language Processing](https://nlpprogress.com/) are (to my mind) two great resources you could get stuck into and that would help you work out where you wanted to go from there.